# Meines wissens vs meinet wissens

Tags: dialect, regional

In a recent discussion we talked about the phrase *meines Wissens* but I recalled a variant with a t: *meine**t** Wissens*. Is this a regionalism or what? If I google it the first dozen hits or so come up from Google Books, but here is an example from a discussion group forum:

> Hey Leute,
>
> Ich habe vor nem guten halben Jahr im tv eine vorschau von der Serie "The Walking Dead" gesehen und die sollte ja eigentlich im Deutschen Fernsehen laufen so hieß es in der vorschau aber sie kam **meinet wissens** noch nicht deswegen wollte ich mal fragen ob hier jemand mehr weiss z.B. wird sie noch ausgestrahlt? wenn ja wann? usw.

Anyone care to comment on the use of this expression?

EDIT: Takkat has pointed out something one of his comments that must be so obvious to all Native German speakers that they simply took it for granted: that *meinetwegen* is a real word but *meinetwisses* isn’t. Could it be that the use of *meinetwissens* has nothing to do with the regions where *wat/dat* is spoken, and simply a case of people transferring over from the correct form (*meinetwegen*) to a similar-sounding one that is incorrect?

Comment: Wahrscheinlich einfach ein Tippfehler. Der Text ist ohnehin schlampig.

Comment: Auf welcher Tastatur liegen s und t denn so, dass das ein Tippfehler sein könnte?

Comment: Also einen größeren Wind um nichts habe ich selten hier gesehen. Der Typ hat einfach geschrieben wie er im Dialekt spricht, und manche machen daraus jetzt eine Wissenschaft hier... *kopfschüttel*

Comment: On the topic of your edit’s question: No, I think that is highly unlikely. *Meinetwegen* and *meinethalben* are usually regarded as so fixed expressions that nobody would assume *any* relevance to *meines Wissens*. Oftentimes people might use the dative case (*meinem Wissen …*) which doesn’t work at all for *meinetwegen* (*meinemwegen*?) indicating that most people would understand the phrase as two words.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @sollniss already mentioned, this is just a regional pronunciation of the word written literally. The tone of the text is rather informal and the author probably didn't worry too much about using standard spelling (you can tell just by looking at `nem` instead of `einem`).

However, this is not exclusive of *Berlinerisch*. This map shows other regions that feature the pronunciation (it is particularly popular in the so-called *Ruhrgebiet*):

[image: pronunciation map]

It's also worth noting that it is normally believed that the pronunciation with the `/t/` is newer and came from the standard pronunciation, which is actually not true. It's completely the other way around. The `/t/` sound shifted towards an `/s/` sound.

Sources:

http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-1/f17a-c/

https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zweite_Lautverschiebung#Phase_1

Comment: I don't think you can conclude that "meinet" is said where people say "wat". I am from cologne and I say "wat", but OP's sentence sounds odd to me. I can't quite think of anything off the top of my head where I would say "meinet", except for "meinetwegen".

Comment: @Em1 while it might not be common in certain words, it is certainly not exclusive of 'wat'. In the atlas page a few other words are mentioned. The last map in that page might be particularly relevant to your comment, since it doesn't seem to be used in Köln but is also definitely not exclusive of Berlin.

Comment: I would say that using the third map would have been better. But other than that, this answer is good. +1

Comment: Agree, the third one is much more relevant and indeed, I wouldn't say "neuet".

Comment: Changed the image to the more relevant map.

Answer (score 4):

*Meinet* is the berlinerisch version of *meines*.

Comment: Willkommen auf German Language und vielen Dank für deinen Beitrag. Vielleicht kannst du deine Antwort noch ein wenig ausbauen, evtl. mit Beispielen? Klicke dazu einfach auf [edit]. Interessant wäre z.B auch der Bezug zu *meinetwegen*, *meinetwillen* (nur so als Idee).

Comment: @Takkat: Ich finde die Idee jede Antwort zu einem Aufsatz auszubauen furchtbar. Statt die Essenz dessen, was gesagt werden soll, maximal zu verdichten wird verdünnt und gelabert bis zum dorthinaus.

Comment: @userunknown: die Antwort hatte schon 2 delete votes aus der First-Post-Review (das ist also nicht meine Idee!). Wenn alle deine Meinung teilten, dann müssten wir dies nicht jedesmal auf Neue diskutieren.

Comment: @Takkat: Du hast es geschrieben, also rechne ich die Meinung Dir zu. Hier hat die Antwort 3 Upvotes und 0 Downvotes. Wenn Du meinst dass die Wörter 'meinetwillen' und 'meinetwegen' zur Klärung der gestellten Frage beitragen solltest Du eine eigene Antwort schreiben und Dich darüber auslassen. Ich sehe allerdings keinen Zusammenhang mit Berliner Dialekt und drohe vorsorglich mit einem Downvote. :) Um sollniss vor ähnlichem Unbill zu bewahren rate ich ihm von diesem Irrweg ab. :)

Comment: I don't know why anyone would ask a question if he only wanted the simplest most literal answer. I come to this group because I enjoy the discussions. A correct answer is always appreciated, but the hope is always that it might lead to further unexpected areas of interest. I honestly feel a bit cheated if someone answers my question with a single line and thereby ends the discussion. (Nothing personal, @solniss)

Comment: @userunknown [Siehe die alte Meta-Diskussion](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/761/should-we-delete-answers-that-give-no-explanation-or-references-whatsoever). Kurz zusammengefasst: Kurz ist zwar nicht löschwürdig, ausführlicher wäre aber besser. So, wie diese Antwort steht, könnte man meinen, dass *meinet* im Berlinischen eine Variante ist, die keine Entsprechung in anderen Wörtern hat. Wir wissen natürlich, dass es *det* (oder *ditte*), *wat* und *et* heißt, aber weiß das der OP? Weiß das der User, der später dazukommt? **Das** sollte der erweiterte Kontext einer Antwort sein.

Comment: Ich halte mich aber zurück, weil ich für Berlinisch kein Experte bin. Und @Takkat damit du auch siehst, dass ich was dazugebe (auch nur, weil ich zwei Kommentare gebraucht habe).

Comment: @MartyGreen: Die Zielsetzung der SO-Seiten ist es Wissen darzustellen, nicht Meinung. Diskussion ist immer ein Symptom für Unsicherheit und kann notwendig sein, aber erwünscht per se ist sie nicht.

Comment: @Jan: Du weißt selbst zu wenig um eine längere Antwort zu schreiben, wünschst es aber von sollniss. Wenn sollniss auch nicht mehr sagen kann - hätte er dann die Antwort unterlassen sollen?

Comment: @userunknown Ich weiß, dass ich sehr weit weg von Berlin wohne und herstamme, deswegen hätte ich anderen, die wahrscheinlich mehr wissen, den Vortritt gelassen. Sofern aber nichts gekommen wäre nach einem Tag oder zwei, hätte ich mein Wissen in eine Antwort gegossen.

Comment: So ein Drama hier. Ich komme aus Region Berlin und bis es gewohnt, dass Leute "meinet" für "meines" sagen. Es ist halt üblich ein "s" durch ein "t" zu ersetzen bei manchen Wörtern. Was soll ich dazu jetzt noch groß sagen? Ich bin weder Linguistiker noch Sprachhistoriker, also kann ich euch leider nicht sagen, warum es "meinetwegen" heißt. Der Duden meint jedoch, dass "meinet" eine alte Version von "meinen" ist. Daher würde ich mal behaupen, dass das "meinet" in meinetwegen ein anderes "meinet" ist, als das von OP.

Comment: I am glad to hear from you Solniss. I upvoted your answer for being the first, but gave the coveted check-mark to @clinch for his detailed and informative contribution. On the question of drama: yes, it seems like a tempest in a teapot over such a small matter. But behind it is a bigger phenomenon: there are two very different world-views at play here: one, who thinks that the "drama" detracts from the value of this forum; and another, who thinks that it contributes to the value.

Answer (score 1):

#### The only widely accepted spelling is "meines Wissens"

It is as early as the 16th Century when the term "meines Wissens" was used in written German documents. The earliest Google reference dates [back to 1539](https://books.google.de/books?id=HkxZAAAAcAAJ&dq=%22meines%20wissens%22&pg=PT30#v=onepage&q=%22meines%20wissens%22&f=false):

[image]

Another spelling was never used, at least not within the limits we can search by Google (search hits for "meinet wissens" were exclusively from scanning errors of small prints or Fraktur).

#### Misspellings are not rare

Still, results in all newer media including poorly reviewed journals, chats, blogs, or forums reveal that **"meinet Wissens"** is found surprisingly often with variants such as **"meinet wissens"** or very often **"meinetwissens"** (we event found entries for "meinentwissens").

[image]

#### Origin of "meinet"

It remains speculative as to why people use this spelling. One reason may be that it was influenced by regional dialects where "meines" is pronounced "meinet".

Another rather likely reason may be that people who are not sure about the correct spelling use similar words they know such as *meinetwegen*. This would also explain why the occurence as a composite (which it is not) outnumbers other variants.

Comment: I wonder why you find meinetwegen to be more legitimate than meinetwissens. I thought they were cut from the same cloth. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @MartyGreen [**meinetwegen**](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/meinetwegen) is a common German word, **meinetwissens** never was. I believe this is the main reason for the misspelling and I could not find **any** reference that it is more common in  or around of Berlin or the Rhineland.